# android adb strace not found on windows

Tags: android, adb, strace

I want to log all the system calls of an Android app. When I run the command `adb shell strace` I get `/system/bin/sh: strace: not found` I am on windows 10 and I have installed the Android platform tools 28.0.1. I have tried to use the command `make` on adb shell but it was not found.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Windows. Android runs a limited version of linux, so not all linux commands can operate in Android. Google for "busybox"' it might help you.

Comment: @TDG the 'strace' command should run on Android  https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/strace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to use the strace shell it is necessary to have a device with an x86 system image

Answer (score 2):

download strace from this site:
http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/18/android-runtime-strace
(click hyperlink "strace for Android")

type adb shell to enter in adb shell
use /system/xbin/su -c "system/bin/sh -" (to get to root)
then place the file in system/bin (downloaded from above link), while being in root.
ps to see processes.
run strace!

command: strace -p